# CiviMail --> Sparkpost -- Invalid links in header & footer

Tags: civimail, sparkpost

I've installed CiviCRM 5.37.2 on a WordPress website, set up a new email address, got the DNS records working, Sparkpost is happy, did a tiny test email blast, which flowed through CiviMail and Sparkpost successfully with no bounces, but only 1 of 3 emails got delivered.

I found one problem.  The links in the CiviMail header and footer are being modified with a suffix which I guess is normal. But the resulting links are invalid. For example, the link in the header is https://votersfirstwi.org  but it gets delivered as https://votersfirstwi.org/index.php/home/mailing/url/?u=1&qid=4 which is an invalid URL.

My other website also adds a link suffix with CiviMail, but it results in a working link.  I send out thousands of emails with that website, but it doesn't use Sparkpost.

Where is this link modification happening and how do I fix it...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the `index.php` in the links.  I fixed by changing the WordPress Settings --> Permalinks
It was set for Custom Structure and when I changed it to Day and Name it fixed the problem. Now if I could just get the opt-out working I'd be happy...